# HTTPS on ELB to HTTP IIS backend server reporting not secure message

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis-8, amazon-elb

I'm not exactly sure if this is the correct wording for my issue but in our environment, the standard is to use an AWS ELB that accepts HTTPS traffic and does the SSL termination at the ELB level. From there, all traffic between the ELB and web server is done using regular HTTP. This configuration seems to work well for our web servers running on apace or nginx but I need to use the same format for one of our IIS servers and it appears to be giving me some issues.

I can get hit the ELB and access the website but it gives me a "Not Secure" message in the URL bar. Some background information on the setup is below:

- ELB created with a listener for HTTPS(443) to instance protocol/port HTTP(80)
- wildcard SSL cert installed on the ELB
- same SSL cert installed on the IIS server (friendly name of cert set to CN of the wildcard cert)
- http(80) binding set on the IIS website

I've found multiple posts about the URL Rewrite module redirecting HTTP to HTTPS though I'm not sure this is what I want to do. Our ELB and IIS server are in a secured VPC so HTTPS(on the ELB) to HTTP(IIS webserver) is fine. I thought if I used the URL rewrite method that would be the same as offloading SSL to the webserver?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a [URL Rewrite Module 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47337) rule to redirect based on a URL pattern does not mean offloading SSL to IIS and you don't need to install the SSL certificate on IIS of you've already uploaded your certificate to ELB.

After installing URL Rewrite on IIS, normally you'd write your rewrite rules in `Web.config` as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
    <outboundRules>
      <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
      </rule>
    </outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

You might find other useful info on how to troubleshoot certificate errors [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/load-balancer-certificate/).

Answer (score 0):

When you go to an HTTPS website, if some additional assets that need to be loaded (such as images, CSS files, JS files, etc.) are coming from HTTP locations, then your browser will/may complain about the connection not being secure.

Use the Developer Tools of your web browser and see if there are any connections being made (back to your server, or to another server) that is HTTP and not HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my issue was actually a problem with the certificate and the dns name i was using. We use a wildcard ssl cert (ie, *.example.com) and my CNAME record for my ELB was set to something like test01.stage.example.com.

Once i changed the CNAME record to just test01.example.com and deleted the ssl cert from the IIS server, everything worked normally. A bit of misunderstanding on my part about wildcard certs. I just assumed *.example.com would catch anything even if it was 3rd or 4th level domain.